# Login to Openstack Horizon Failed

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I setup Openstack Horizon using the official Guide https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/ussuri/install/install-ubuntu.html

But now I can not login. I checked the credentials with the CLI client and they work without a problem.

In /var/log/apache2/error.log i see the following.

```
[Sat Sep 19 16:10:39.087944 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 32076:tid 140116107127744] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 19 16:10:39.088076 2020] [core:notice] [pid 32076:tid 140116107127744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:47.362377 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32077:tid 140115930097408] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scss/namespace.py:172: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python 3.0, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:47.362467 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32077:tid 140115930097408]   argspec = inspect.getargspec(function)
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:47.494122 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32077:tid 140115930097408] [remote 172.17.2.20:48130] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cinderclient/client.py:23: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:47.494163 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32077:tid 140115930097408] [remote 172.17.2.20:48130]   import imp
[Sat Sep 19 16:11:47.924935 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 32092:tid 140115850520320] [client 172.17.5.2:47206] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/bin/keystone-wsgi-public
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:47.926407 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32077:tid 140115930097408] [remote 172.17.2.20:48130] INFO openstack_auth.forms Login failed for user "admin" using domain "Default", remote address 172.17.2.20.
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:49.704606 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32078:tid 140115988846336] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scss/namespace.py:172: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated since Python 3.0, use inspect.signature() or inspect.getfullargspec()
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:49.704674 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32078:tid 140115988846336]   argspec = inspect.getargspec(function)
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:49.824541 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32078:tid 140115988846336] [remote 172.17.2.20:48134] /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cinderclient/client.py:23: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
[Sat Sep 19 14:11:49.824582 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 32078:tid 140115988846336] [remote 172.17.2.20:48134]   import imp
```

What can be the problem here and how to fix this? If you need additional information just ask and I will supply them.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the apache2.conf according to https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/117138/failed-to-login-to-dashboard/ helped in my case

Comment: The configuration is already like that.